# Add to matrix missing elements (for list of time series)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays, time-series

This question is an extension of the [43122](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43122/find-missing-values-in-time-series-and-fill-them-with-na). I’ve looked through many interesting post (like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/how-do-i-obtain-an-intersection-of-two-or-more-list-of-lists-conditioned-on-the?rq=1)) but (as always) missed the direct matching.
So the setting is simple:

```
datum = {{{2, g},         {6, h}, {7, k}}, 
         {{2, a}, {4, b},         {7, d}}, 
                 {{4, e},         {7, f}}}
```

Note: numbers `{2, 4, 6, 7}` are ordered but arbitrary (that differs with related question that seems promising).
I need reliable and possibly concise method suitable for working with matrices of the size around 1000 x 1000 (that are as a rule time series). May be some specific ad hoc build-in methods.

Expected result ("X" any constant, i.e. `Missing[]`):

```
{
 {{2, g},   {4, "X"}, {6, h},   {7, k}},
 {{2, a},   {4, b},   {6, "X"}, {7, d}},
 {{2, "X"}, {4, e},   {6, "X"}, {7, f}}
}
```

PS. My current method seems, sort of, naive and long.

```
sample = Union @@ (#[[All, 1]] & /@ datum)
(* {2, 4, 6, 7} *)
step1 = Complement[sample, #[[All, 1]]] & /@ datum;
step2 = Thread[{#, Array["X" &, Length[#]]}] & /@ step1;
MapThread[Union, {datum, step2}]
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Apply[List,
  Normal@*KeySort /@ KeyUnion[
    AssociationThread @@@ Transpose /@ datum
    , "X" &
  ]
  , {2}]
```

**Explanation**

`AssociationThread @@@ Transpose /@ datum` generates a list of `Association`s with the first elements (2, 4, 6, and 7) as the `Key`s. `KeyUnion` then takes each of those `Association`s and adds the `Key`s from the other `Association`s that are missing; the second argument specifies what should be done in the situation where a `Key` is `Missing`. `KeySort` does exactly what it seems to, `Normal` changes the `Association` to a list of `Rule`s, and finally, we change each of the `Rule`s to a `List` using `Apply`.

**Old version:**

```
assocs = Association /@ Apply[Rule, datum, {2}];
assocsUnion = KeySort /@ KeyUnion@assocs /. Missing[__] :> "X";
Apply[List, Normal@assocsUnion, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datum = {{{2, g}, {6, h}, {7, k}}, {{2, a}, {4, b}, {7, d}}, {{4, e}, {7, f}}};

With[{uni = Union@Cases[datum, a_Integer :> {a, "X"}, 3]},
  Sort /@ DeleteDuplicatesBy[First] /@ (Join[#, uni] & /@ datum)] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an entirely pre V10 method:

```
With[{xtra = Thread[{Union@Flatten@datum[[All, All, 1]], Missing[]}]},
  Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Join[#, xtra], #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &] & /@ datum
 ]
```

which gives:

```
(*

{{{2, g}, {4, Missing[]}, {6, h}, {7, k}}, {{2, a}, {4, b}, {6, 
   Missing[]}, {7, d}}, {{2, Missing[]}, {4, e}, {6, Missing[]}, {7, 
   f}}}

*)
```

Answer (score 2):

With set functions and a pure listable function

```
With[{indices = Union @@ datum[[All, All, 1]]},
 Union[Function[{v}, {v, Missing[]}, Listable][
     Complement[indices, #[[All, 1]]]], #] & /@ datum]
```

> {{{2, g}, {4, Missing[]}, {6, h}, {7, k}}, {{2, a}, {4, b}, {6, 
>      Missing[]}, {7, d}}, {{2, Missing[]}, {4, e}, {6, Missing[]}, {7, 
>      f}}}

Hope this helps.