# Matching timestamped data

Tags: string-manipulation, data, date-and-time, time-series

I bet this question is a gimme for most of you guys, but I'm having a bit o' trouble figuring it out. Thanks ahead of time for your input and help.

Soooo, I have two datasets where column 1 is a timestamp and column 2 is the data point at that time step. My timestamps have been converted to AbsoluteTime to make things easier. Since my datasets start at different times of year, I would like to be able to sync them up via timestamps so I can perform calculations on them.

```
s1 = {{3534364800, 0}, {3534365700, 0}, {3534366600, 12.3}, {3534367500, 53.8}, {3534368400, 32.1}, {3534369300, 10.8}, {3534370200, 0}, {3534371100, 0}};
s2 = {{3534368400, 31.1}, {3534369300, 10}, {3534370200, .5}, {3534371100, 0}, {3534372000, 15.2}, {3534372900, 8.8}, {3534373800, 0}, {3534374700, 0}};
```

Small snippet of the code. Essentially I would like the code to match up the timestamps, so the the first set needs to match up with the second set.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches of the timestamps or within some tolerance / interval ?

Comment: Exact matches would be best.

Comment: @sanjayr, you may find post [103505](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103505/add-to-matrix-missing-elements-for-list-of-time-series) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data tables from the question:

```
tb1 = {{3534364800, 0}, {3534365700, 0}, {3534366600, 12.3}, {3534367500, 
    53.8}, {3534368400, 32.1}, {3534369300, 10.8}, {3534370200, 
    0}, {3534371100, 0}};
tb2 = {{3534368400, 31.1}, {3534369300, 10}, {3534370200, .5}, {3534371100, 
    0}, {3534372000, 15.2}, {3534372900, 8.8}, {3534373800, 0}, {3534374700, 
    0}};
```

Indexes to demonstrate the matching:

```
index1 = AssociationThread @@ Transpose[tb1];
index2 = AssociationThread @@ Transpose[tb2];
```

Common tiimestamps:

```
commonTS = LongestCommonSequence[tb1[[All, 1]], tb2[[All, 1]]]

(*{3534368400, 3534369300, 3534370200, 3534371100}*)
```

Joined data tables:

```
TableForm[Transpose@{commonTS, index1 /@ commonTS, index2 /@ commonTS}, 
 TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"timestamp", "tb1 vals", "tb2 vals"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the `TimeSeries` construct instead of messing with the raw data.

For instance, convert your lists to two `TimeSeries` objects:

```
ts1 = TimeSeries[{DateList[#1], #2} & @@@ {{3534364800, 0}, {3534365700, 0}, 
         {3534366600, 12.3}, {3534367500, 53.8}, {3534368400, 32.1}, {3534369300, 10.8}, 
         {3534370200, 0}, {3534371100, 0}}
      ]

ts2 = TimeSeries[{DateList[#1], #2} & @@@ {{3534368400, 31.1}, {3534369300, 10}, 
         {3534370200, .5}, {3534371100, 0}, {3534372000, 15.2}, 
         {3534372900, 8.8}, {3534373800, 0}, {3534374700, 0}}
      ]
```

[image: ts1]
[image: ts2]

As you can see, they are automatically aligned:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then perform mathematical operations on the `TimeSeries` objects: the operations will only be performed in those regions where both TimeSeries coincide:

```
ts1 - ts2
```

[image: difference]

You can more clearly see the results of this operation by looking at the values directly:

```
ts1 - ts2 // Normal
```

[image: normal form]

And the difference can be plotted directly as well:

```
DateListPlot[ts1 - ts2]
```

[image: difference plot]